# In information entropy, how do nats relate to any representation of states?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Calculating the information entropy depends on taking the logarithms of probabilities in some base. If I use base 2, then the entropy is in "bits". The measure of bits is close to the representation of states as a binary tree and binary digits.

Is there a representation that corresponds to "nats", calculating the entropy using ln instead of log base 2?

For "bits" and log base 2, I can use the Huffman Encoding strategy to encode my states such that the weighted average of the states is close to the information entropy using log base 2. For example, if I calculate the probability of all the 2-card blackjack hands, I can build a binary tree and serialize the states as

| Value | Representation |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 0100111 |
| 16 | 0011 |
| 20 | 100 |
| 21 | 00010 |

If I use ln instead of log base 2, the resulting entropy is in "nats".

| Measure | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Weighted average length | 3.979 |
| Entropy (bits) | 3.93419124 |
| Entropy (nats) | 2.726973564 |

The log base 2 value corresponds roughly to a binary tree / binary representation, but that doesn't work for nats.

Is there a representation that corresponds to the "nats" value?

Comment: Since $e$ is irrational, there is no simple discrete representation.

Comment: Absolutely! But 1) the binary "bits" are irrational, too, and 2) I wonder if there is some corresponding logarithmic measure. Musical notes are logarithmic. So I'm working if there's some clever way to represent nats that isn't necessarily digital. Likely not, but I wonder :)

Comment: No no no.  Binary bits have precisely TWO alternatives.  A single yes/no question resolves a single bit.  There is no such analogous discrete entity of any sort for nats.

Comment: _the binary "bits" are irrational_
huh, what??

Comment: Sorry I should have said the log2 *entropy measure* in "bits" is irrational: 3.93419124 above